# Two down arrows over specific separator lines of an array

Tags: floats, arrows, arrays

I need to make a figure like the attached image, which contains multiple arrays, two down arrows over the specific separator lines of the first array and text above these two arrows. I could make the arrays in align environment but the problem is arrows and text above them. I used the code below to make the arrays as a figure:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{align*}
    \overrightarrow{P}_{1} \
    &\left[
    \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \alpha_3 & \alpha_4 & \alpha_5 & \alpha_6 & \alpha_7 & \alpha_8 & \alpha_9 \\
    \beta_1 & \beta_2 & \beta_3 & \beta_4 & \beta_5 & \beta_6 & \beta_7 & \beta_8 & \beta_9 \\
    \end{array}
    \right] \\
    \overrightarrow{P}_{2} \
    &\left[
    \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \alpha^\prime_1 & \alpha^\prime_2 & \alpha^\prime_3 & \alpha^\prime_4 & \alpha^\prime_5 & \alpha^\prime_6 & \alpha^\prime_7 & \alpha^\prime_8 & \alpha^\prime_9 \\
    \beta^\prime_1 & \beta^\prime_2 & \beta^\prime_3 & \beta^\prime_4 & \beta^\prime_5 & \beta^\prime_6 & \beta^\prime_7 & \beta^\prime_8 & \beta^\prime_9 \\
    \end{array}
    \right] \\
    \\
    \overrightarrow{S}_{1} \
    &\left[
    \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \alpha_3 & \alpha^\prime_4 & \alpha^\prime_5 & \alpha^\prime_6 & \alpha^\prime_7 & \alpha^\prime_8 & \alpha_9 \\
    \beta_1 & \beta_2 & \beta_3 & \beta^\prime_4 & \beta^\prime_5 & \beta^\prime_6 & \beta^\prime_7 & \beta^\prime_8 & \beta_9 \\
    \end{array}
    \right] \\
    \overrightarrow{S}_{2} \
    &\left[
    \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \alpha^\prime_1 & \alpha^\prime_2 & \alpha^\prime_3 & \alpha_4 & \alpha_5 & \alpha_6 & \alpha_7 & \alpha_8 & \alpha^\prime_9 \\
    \beta^\prime_1 & \beta^\prime_2 & \beta^\prime_3 & \beta_4 & \beta_5 & \beta_6 & \beta_7 & \beta_8 & \beta^\prime_9 \\
    \end{array}
    \right]
\end{align*}
\caption{An example}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the new `tikzmark` library, which contains the fabulous command `\tikzmarknode`, was uploaded to CTAN and became part of the standard TeX installations, there is no longer a real need to translate existing tables or matrices to Ti*k*Z since now you can use `\tikzmarknode` to do all the things that were harder to accomplish before. That is, you can keep what you have and just add the annotations with Ti*k*Z and with minimal effort.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\vspace*{0.6cm}
\begin{align*}
    \overrightarrow{P}_{1} \
    &\left[
    \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \tikzmarknode{a3}{\alpha_3} & \tikzmarknode{a4}{\alpha_4} & \alpha_5 & \alpha_6 & \alpha_7 & \tikzmarknode{a8}{\alpha_8} & \tikzmarknode{a9}{\alpha_9} \\
    \beta_1 & \beta_2 & \beta_3 & \beta_4 & \beta_5 & \beta_6 & \beta_7 & \beta_8 & \beta_9 \\
    \end{array}
    \right] \\
    \overrightarrow{P}_{2} \
    &\left[
    \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \alpha^\prime_1 & \alpha^\prime_2 & \alpha^\prime_3 & \alpha^\prime_4 & \alpha^\prime_5 & \alpha^\prime_6 & \alpha^\prime_7 & \alpha^\prime_8 & \alpha^\prime_9 \\
    \beta^\prime_1 & \beta^\prime_2 & \beta^\prime_3 & \beta^\prime_4 & \beta^\prime_5 & \beta^\prime_6 & \beta^\prime_7 & \beta^\prime_8 & \beta^\prime_9 \\
    \end{array}
    \right] \\
    \\
    \overrightarrow{S}_{1} \
    &\left[
    \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \alpha_3 & \alpha^\prime_4 & \alpha^\prime_5 & \alpha^\prime_6 & \alpha^\prime_7 & \alpha^\prime_8 & \alpha_9 \\
    \beta_1 & \beta_2 & \beta_3 & \beta^\prime_4 & \beta^\prime_5 & \beta^\prime_6 & \beta^\prime_7 & \beta^\prime_8 & \beta_9 \\
    \end{array}
    \right] \\
    \overrightarrow{S}_{2} \
    &\left[
    \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \alpha^\prime_1 & \alpha^\prime_2 & \alpha^\prime_3 & \alpha_4 & \alpha_5 & \alpha_6 & \alpha_7 & \alpha_8 & \alpha^\prime_9 \\
    \beta^\prime_1 & \beta^\prime_2 & \beta^\prime_3 & \beta_4 & \beta_5 & \beta_6 & \beta_7 & \beta_8 & \beta^\prime_9 \\
    \end{array}
    \right]
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[line width=1mm,latex-,red] ($(a3.north east)!0.5!(a4.north west)+(0,0.2)$) -- ++(0,0.6) node[black,above]{$P_1$};
\draw[line width=1mm,latex-,red] ($(a8.north east)!0.5!(a9.north west)+(0,0.2)$) -- ++(0,0.6)node[black,above]{$P_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{An example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To understand what's going on here, look e.g. at

```
\draw[line width=1mm,latex-,red] ($(a3.north east)!0.5!(a4.north west)+(0,0.2)$) -- ++(0,0.6) node[black,above]{$P_1$};
```

Here `+(0,0.2)` determines how much the tip (i.e. lower end) of the arrow gets shifted upwards, and `++(0,0.6)` determines the length of the arrow. If you increase `0.2`, the whole arrow will move upwards, and if you increase/decrease `0.6`, the arrow will get longer/shorter.

Comment: `tikzmark` library is indeed powerful, however transforming ``matrix`  to `array` is not so big deal (except that drawing vertical lines require separate command)  ;-). +1 for nice answer!

Comment: @Zarko Well, you are very powerful with tables, so you know better than me that you can do things with tables which are very hard to reproduce with a Ti*k*Z `matrix`. Features that are hard to get with a Ti*k*Z `matrix` include aligning the decimal points and so on. In the present situation I agree that you can use a Ti*k*Z `matrix` in a very elegant way, but at the very moment in which the OP really makes use of `align*` it will be harder. So I guess everything will depend on what the OP ultimately wants to do, which we do not know.

Comment: i agree with you. the tools which you use are depend on task.

Comment: @marmot Thanks for your nice and simple solution. But, is there any way to put a small vertical space between the arrows and the corresponding separator lines?

Comment: @M.Mojrian Sure. I moved them up a bit and added more explanation such that you can adjust them further, if needed.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

since you include this two equations as figure, why not draw them? for example, draw them with `tikz` and use of the library `matrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 9mm and 1.5mm,
   arr/.style = {draw=red, very thick,  Trinagle-, shorten <=1mm},
  mtrx/.style = {matrix of math nodes,
                 nodes={minimum width=2em},
                 left delimiter={[},
                 right delimiter={]},
                 inner ysep=1pt, inner xsep=-2pt}
                    ]
\matrix (m) [mtrx]
{
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \alpha_3 & \alpha_4 & \alpha_5 & \alpha_6 & \alpha_7 & \alpha_8 & \alpha_9 \\
\beta_1  & \beta_2  & \beta_3  & \beta_4  & \beta_5  & \beta_6  & \beta_7  & \beta_8  & \beta_9 \\
};
\node[left=of m] {$\vec{P}=$};
% 
\matrix (n) [mtrx, right=of n0]
{
\alpha_1' & \alpha_2' & \alpha_3' & \alpha_4' & \alpha_5' & \alpha_6' & \alpha_7' & \alpha_8' & \alpha_9' \\
\beta_1'  & \beta_2'  & \beta_3'  & \beta_4'  & \beta_5'  & \beta_6'  & \beta_7'  & \beta_8'  & \beta_9' \\
};
\node[left=of n]{$\vec{S}_1$};
%
\foreach \i in {1,...,8}
{
\draw (m-1-\i.north east) -- (m-2-\i.south east);
\draw (n-1-\i.north east) -- (n-2-\i.south east);
}
\path[arr]
    (m-1-3.north east) -- + (0,0.5) node[above] {$\mathbf{P1}$};
\path[arr]
    (m-1-8.north east) -- + (0,0.5) node[above] {$\mathbf{P2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{An example of applied two-point quantum crossover}
\label{fig:equation}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can place the `P_1` and `P_2` markers using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)'s absolute positioning mechanism - placing it in the `F`ore`G`round of the current page (via `\AddToShipoutPictureFG*`). [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module allows you to capture the x,y coordinates of a `<label>` (set using `\zsavepos{<label>}`) which can be retrieved using `\zposx`/`\zposy` (both expandable).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,zref-savepos,eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    & \\ % Just to leave an empty line
  \overrightarrow{P}_1 \
    & \left[
      \begin{array}{ *{8}{c|} c }
        \alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \alpha_3\zsavepos{P1L} & \zsavepos{P1R}\alpha_4 & \alpha_5 & \alpha_6 & \alpha_7 & \alpha_8\zsavepos{P2L} & \zsavepos{P2R}\alpha_9 \\
        \beta_1 & \beta_2 & \beta_3 & \beta_4 & \beta_5 & \beta_6 & \beta_7 & \beta_8 & \beta_9 \\
      \end{array}
      \right] \\
  \overrightarrow{P}_2 \
    & \left[
      \begin{array}{ *{8}{c|} c }
        \alpha^\prime_1 & \alpha^\prime_2 & \alpha^\prime_3 & \alpha^\prime_4 & \alpha^\prime_5 & \alpha^\prime_6 & \alpha^\prime_7 & \alpha^\prime_8 & \alpha^\prime_9 \\
        \beta^\prime_1 & \beta^\prime_2 & \beta^\prime_3 & \beta^\prime_4 & \beta^\prime_5 & \beta^\prime_6 & \beta^\prime_7 & \beta^\prime_8 & \beta^\prime_9 \\
        \end{array}
      \right] \\
  \\
  \overrightarrow{S}_1 \
    & \left[
      \begin{array}{ *{8}{c|} c }
        \alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \alpha_3 & \alpha^\prime_4 & \alpha^\prime_5 & \alpha^\prime_6 & \alpha^\prime_7 & \alpha^\prime_8 & \alpha_9 \\
        \beta_1 & \beta_2 & \beta_3 & \beta^\prime_4 & \beta^\prime_5 & \beta^\prime_6 & \beta^\prime_7 & \beta^\prime_8 & \beta_9 \\
      \end{array}
      \right] \\
  \overrightarrow{S}_2 \
    & \left[
      \begin{array}{ *{8}{c|} c }
        \alpha^\prime_1 & \alpha^\prime_2 & \alpha^\prime_3 & \alpha_4 & \alpha_5 & \alpha_6 & \alpha_7 & \alpha_8 & \alpha^\prime_9 \\
        \beta^\prime_1 & \beta^\prime_2 & \beta^\prime_3 & \beta_4 & \beta_5 & \beta_6 & \beta_7 & \beta_8 & \beta^\prime_9 \\
      \end{array}
      \right]
\end{align*}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \hspace{0.5\dimexpr\zposx{P1L}sp+\zposx{P1R}sp\relax}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\zposy{P1L}sp+1.5\baselineskip}{\makebox[0pt]{$\substack{P_1 \\ \downarrow}$}}%
  }%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \hspace{0.5\dimexpr\zposx{P2L}sp+\zposx{P2R}sp\relax}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\zposy{P1L}sp+1.5\baselineskip}{\makebox[0pt]{$\substack{P_2 \\ \downarrow}$}}%
  }%
}

\end{document}
```

Above I place two markers around the `array` column divider for each of `P_1` and `P_2` (denoted with a `L`eft and `R`ight suffix) and position the labels to be at the horizontal centre of these markers.

An empty line within the `align*` is left at the top in order to avoid unnecessary interaction with content appearing above the environment.

Since the markers use TeX's `\label`-`\ref`-like system, any change in the location of the markers requires an additional compilation so reference can settle.